# Extracting data from (huge) xml file using php

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have a `.xml` file (original with over 7000 lines, but for testing I have been using one with just 3 lines, in case the size was my problem, but it wasn't) from which I would like to extract the data. However, being an automatically generated thing, it's not terribly pretty, observe:

```
<ROW MODID="182" RECORDID="561">
<COL>
<DATA>
</DATA>
</COL>
<COL>
<DATA>
6 quai St Pierre</DATA>
</COL>
<COL>
<DATA>
</DATA>
</COL>
<COL>
<DATA>
Monsieur</DATA>
</COL>
<COL>
```

etc, etc...
I have already devised the requests I need to run on `Xacobeo`, but I can't seem to get it to work with php. I've tried a multitude of variations, the last one being the following:

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('hellashort.xml');
$xpathvar = new Domxpath($xmldoc);
$queryResult = $xpathvar->query('//COL');
foreach($queryResult as $result){
    echo $result->textContent;
}
```

I tried this code with more aesthetically pleasing files and it works, so how can I get it working with this file?
All suggestions appreciated.
Thanks

**UPDATE**
I checked the short file for errors and realised I hadn't closed an element, so that one works, however the long file contains no errors according to the online checker but still doesn't work.

**UPDATE 2**
The long file now works for the request `/` but returns nothing as soon as they get more complicated, ie: `//ROW/COL[position()=39]/DATA` which return correct results in Xacobeo.
Is it possible for a `.xml` file to be too big to be handled this way? (This file is about 11.2 Mo)

**UPDATE 3 - FIXED**
So I changed my approached and ended up doing it this way:

```
$file=file_get_contents("go.xml");
$xml=simplexml_load_string($file);
$elements=$xml->path('//ROW/COL[position()=1]/DATA');
```

I see why it's called simpleXML, thanks for all the help though

Comment: I would suggest validate the XML using any online tool and also share what error you are getting, or what is happening.

Comment: No errors are showing up (either on screen or in the log), and no result appears... I echoed a couple of random phrases before and after the function to make sure I wasn't getting the white screen of death, and they both show up fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure your server is set to show all available errors.
As variant, put this snippet in the very beginning of your  script.

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Could you then share the error message?

Comment: No errors appear either in the browser or in the apache error log... A `print_r` of the array gives me `DOMNodeList Object ( ) `

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your document has exactly one root element, i.e. an element to contain all the `<ROW>` elements:

```
<DOCUMENT>
<ROW MODID="182" RECORDID="561">
<COL>
<DATA>
</DATA>
</COL>
<COL>
<DATA>
6 quai St Pierre</DATA>
</COL>
<COL>
<DATA>
<!-- ... -->
</DOCUMENT>
```

If you have multiple rows without a root, it’s not a well-formet XML file and it will fail:

```
<ROW MODID="182" RECORDID="561">
<COL>
<DATA>
</DATA>
</COL>
<COL>
<!-- ... -->
</ROW>
<ROW MODID="183" RECORDID="562">
<!-- ... -->
</ROW>
```

Comment: I've checked that, the whole file is contained in a `<RESULTSET>` element.. I'm fairly sure it's being read correctly as the query works when it's just `'/'`