# Filemaker xml export: how to make each row start on a new line?

Tags: xml, filemaker

I'm am a newbie when it comes to xml/xls, but I need to export some records from filemaker as an `.xml` file.
I can manage it that far, but when I open the file, each `<ROW>` tag is on the same line as the last, which makes it very complicated for me.

Filemaker gives the option of making a stylesheet with a httpd request, but I really don't understand what it expects... If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'll be very thankful.

Comment: "*which makes it very complicated for me*" Why is that?

Comment: I'm trying to use a php/xpath request that goes line by line.. Sometimes the rows are broken over two lines so it messes the system up

Comment: I am not a php expert, but xpath has nothing to do with lines, it addresses the nodes.

Comment: "*I'm trying to use a php/xpath request that goes line by line..*" I am afraid that doesn't tell me anything. In XML, white-space is (or at least should be) insignificant. And a ROW will never be broken into two lines, unless you have **content** that contains a carriage return. And that's not a formatting issue.

Comment: I've been having problems addressing the nodes which is why I'm taking an unconventional approach.. If you guys want to take a look at that problem, it's posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390065/extracting-data-from-huge-xml-file-using-php/37408792#37408792)

Comment: @JessicaChambers I suspect it could be a *namespace* issue. Hard to be sure without seeing the input alongside the exact expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you just want a "pretty-printed" XML file as the result, use this as your XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" 
exclude-result-prefixes="xalan">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="2"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is a better answer, more to the OP request. Would the xsl:copy-of applied to the root node do the job better?

Comment: @NicolaiKant It would do exactly the same thing - no better nor worse.

Comment: I am not arguing, I just think the syntax is simpler and easier to remember.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on @michael.hor257k answer, using xsl:copy-of instead of xsl:copy

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xalan">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="2" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beverly Voth wrote a book on the subject, but FileMaker forums are probably the best place to find information you need.

Majority of xml will not have carriage returns between nodes as they do not matter for the data structure. What you are looking for is "pretty" xml. Some of the editors will display xml as pretty or will give you this an option, e.g Notepad++ xml plugin has it.

If you just need to work out the xml structure and do not have any tools apart from a simple text editor, just batch replace "

> Filemaker gives the option of making a stylesheet with a httpd
>   request, but I really don't understand what it expects...

FileMaker does not make XSLT stylesheets, you have to provide one or link to the one available on the web.